# htaccess ignore part of query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

It is possible to write a .htaccess rule to **ignore** part of the query string but still keep it in the url (without redirection)?

i need a way to ignore query string(s) starts with the **utm_** like they are absent (invisible to the backend scripts) but still present in the browser URL because the query string will be captured by the JavaScript analytics scripts (thats why solutions with the redirection unacceptable).

lets say i have an url without query string: https://example.com/bla/hello

or with query string: https://example.com/anything?hello=world

then i need to add a query string part **utm_source=123** which could be positioned anywhere among the other query string elements

some pages of the site stops working or starts behaving different when im adding a query string to the url for example https://example.com/?utm_source=123 throws 404

if it is possible, could you help me with the rules ?

Comment: So you just want to rewrite the URL internally then. Yes, mod_rewrite is perfectly capable of doing that.

Comment: could you help with such a rule ? i tried several but without success, not enough knowledge :(

Comment: Well, the thing is, this isn’t that trivial ... There is no "string replace" functionality at this level, so you would need to capture what comes before and after such a parameter, and then connect those two parts to a new query string, “leaving out” the part that is to be erased ... And then you might have to additionally “loop” this somehow, to get all possible parameters ... I might really be easier if you taught your app to be less restrictive, and _ignore_ GET parameters it doesn’t know.

Comment: but i need those GET params so 3d party JS could capture them and use in analysis

Comment: Then make your app not have a problem with them in the first place.